# Youtube api v3 update video with status publishAt

Tags: php, laravel-5, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to set status.publishAt but `return 400` with message `The request metadata is invalid`

Here my code:

```
$videos = $youtube->videos->listVideos('id,snippet,status', array(
  'id' => $videoId,
));

$updateVideo = $videos[0];
$date = "2016-10-20T20:00:00.00+00:00";

$updateVideo['status']['embeddable'] = true;
$updateVideo['status']['privacyStatus'] = 'private';
$updateVideo['status']['publicStatsViewable'] =true;
$updateVideo['status']['publishAt'] = $date;
$videoUpdateResponse = $youtube->videos->update('id,snippet,status', $updateVideo);
dd($videoUpdateResponse);
exit();
```

Where's wrong? Please help me! Thanks

Comment: Can you set the `publishAt` date to be a future date & try

Answer (score 1):

From Ibrahim Ulukaya's answer he is one of the developer of youtube api.

To change a field in upload method, you have to put all other fields you get, otherwise the update method will think you are trying to empty them.

In your case, you should include "license" and "publicStatsViewable" in your PUT request just as you get them from your "GET" request.