How to set video details when uploading to YouTube with Python API client
Follow-up on How to set video language when uploading to YouTube with Python API client, after successfully setting the video language.
I am uploading videos to YouTube programmatically following the official guide:
  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=title,
      description=description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=10,  # Music.
      defaultLanguage=language,  # Title and description launguage.
      defaultAudioLanguage=language,  # Video language.
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus="public"
      embeddable=True,
      publicStatsViewable=True,
      publishAt="2024-04-04T18:00:00+00:00",
      selfDeclaredMadeForKids=True,
    )
  )

I can upload the video, set the title, the description, their language, the video's language, the scheduled publishing date, etc. I can also upload a thumbnail.
But the web interface has other details that I can't see how to set programmatically:

Does the video contain altered content
Allow automatic chapters and key moments
Allow automatic concepts
Don't allow remixing

I know the documentation does not mention these settings and so they don't seem possible to set. But it does not mention the video's language either, and yet (from How to set video language when uploading to YouTube with Python API client), it's possible to set it with defaultAudioLanguage. I wonder if someone knows the right parameters for these details as well, which are missing from the documentation.
How can I set these additional details?

It does not appear that you can do this programmatically from the public API (see JSON representation of a video), which does not list anything similar to the fields you mention.
Here is one counter-example: even though the video's audio language is missing from the official guide with sample code, it appears in the JSON representation of a video:

snippet.defaultAudioLanguage  string
The default_audio_language property specifies the language spoken in the video's default audio track.


The documentation doesn't mention the video's language either, and yet it's possible to set it with defaultAudioLanguage. I wonder if something similar exists for those other details and I updated the question.

@miguelmorin defaultAudioLanguage is part of the video resource JSON though, and I don't see any other fields that could correspond to the ones you're looking for
